# How remove some error property in response apollo graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

[image]

Hi there. I'm new to Apollo Graphql. and find some errors like in the red box. My question is how can I remove the error message in the red box for production. Thanks for any feedback

Comment: Don't run your apollo server in dev mode and it shouldn't emit errors with stack traces

Comment: It's virtually impossible to help you without the server code... could you edit your question to include it?

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the stack trace from your errors by updating apollo server params
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#omitting-or-including-stacktrace